# One font from windows fonts folder not working in my SVG

Tags: svg, fonts

I try to use specific fonts directly installed on my Windows in my SVG. It's for a local use.

Many fonts work well, with space in their name or not, some custom font works too but this font doesn't work, i try all possible syntax, nothing to do.

Here my SVG code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<text x="0" y="1em" font-family="Alte Haas Grotesk" font-size="270.66875pt" fill="#000" >Test</text>
</svg>
```

You can download the ttf here:
https://1fichier.com/?1k6e2h4bja

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you sure the font is not just rendering off the bottom of the SVG? You aren't specifying a size for your SVG, so by default it will be 300x150px (in a browser). The position of your text is at y=360px (1em=270pt=360px). If the font has a small X-Height, it may be off the bottom of the page.  Times Roman almost is.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It's not a size problem 'cause i see the text entirely, but in a default font like Time new roman or arial, i don't now what it is precisely.